# User registration and authentication by e-mail address instead of username

Tags: django, authentication

I don't want to write custom auth backend and I think such common task must been already solved by some 3rd party app.

I did some googling and skimming through SO but found only https://bitbucket.org/hakanw/django-email-usernames/wiki/Home which is quite old (2008). Are any other alternatives already available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say, "I don't want to write custom auth backend" but a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends) is exactly the way that Django expects you to solve this problem, and moreover, it's really quite straightforward—much simpler than installing a third-party app.

Here's a simple approach, in which a user has one e-mail address, stored in the `email` field of the built-in `User` object.

First, think about case-sensitivity. Even though the local part of an e-mail address (the part before the @ sign) may be case-sensitive (depending on the e-mail provider), Django's built-in `auth` application treats e-mail addresses as being case-insensitive (for example, when deciding which users to e-mail in response to a password reset request). So it's probably best for you to treat them that way too.

Second, ensure that two users can't share the same e-mail address. You could do this by hand in the database:

```sql
ALTER TABLE auth_user ADD UNIQUE INDEX (email);
```

or if you are using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), then make a schema migration for the `auth` application where you call [`db.create_unique('auth_user', 'email')`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html#db-create-unique).

To enforce case-insensitive uniqueness, you should ensure that the collation on the `email` field is case-insensitive. I found that it already was, but you might do something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY email VARCHAR(75) COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

(Or `ascii_general_ci` if you don't support [international e-mail addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4952).)

Third, [define your authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend), perhaps in `mysite/backends.py`:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Authenticate against django.contrib.auth.models.User using
    e-mail address instead of username.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact = username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Fourth, add your authentication backend to your `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('mysite.backends.EmailAuthenticationBackend',)
```

Comment: Thank you, Gareth. Now I see.

Comment: One more question, though. Is there a way to enforce uniqueness of email in python code, for example on model definition level?

Comment: If you are defining your own model for user profiles (instead of using the built-in `User` model in the `auth` application) then you can set `unique=True` on any field.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the email as the username i.e. users enter their emails and you assign that to both username and email attributes (or jus username and leave email blank, whatever suits your needs better).

I'm using such approach in one of the websites and it works fine. It's based on django.contrib.auth which is probably the most mature and common solution so I would try to use that.

The library you mentioned is quite simple, but it introduces some customization. What it provides might be achieved by what I proposed. My solution is simpler, their solution is cleaner and it's up to you to decide :)

Comment: You approach is good (really simple, I like it) but has a problem because of username field is limited by `max_length=30` so long email won't fit in. Can this problem be sidestepped somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at https://bitbucket.org/hakanw/django-email-usernames/src/adfb6a88a2d2/email_usernames/management.py (part of the app you mentioned). This modifies the table to allow longer emails. I have done something similiar in my production database. For development I think this won't be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an app for that. This is a very simple to do. In my project, every user has a profile, and each profile can have multiple emails. The user can sign into the system using any of his emails address.

```
class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    '''Logs users using email addresses rather than usernames
    '''
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        '''Try to log users on using any of their emails
        facebook does that too.
        username is an email address.
        '''
        try:
            email = Email.objects.get(email=username)
            user_profile = email.content_object
            if user_profile.user.check_password(password):
                return user_profile.user
        except Email.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I am also adding a logon by phone number, people apparently memorise their phone numbers better than email addresses. so you could replace the line that says

```
email = Email.objects.get(email=username)
```

with

```
phone = Phone.objects.get(phone=username)
```

I normally have the custom auth backends above the contrib one, so that can work as a failover when this one fails to authenticate.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # an email logon backend
    'account.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
    # django builtin auth will be diabled in the future
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

Comment: The `get_user` method on your `EmailAuthBackend` class is identical to the `get_user` method on the `ModelBackend` class from which it derives. So you could simplify your code by removing this method.

Comment: Thanks @GarethRees I copied code quickly from my project. I cannot recall what custom actions I wanted to add when I overwritten that method.